# .ASPXAUTH exprires so soon

Tags: asp.net, .aspxauth

I have these on my web.config of my root directory

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
<forms loginUrl="Login.aspx"
       protection="All"
       timeout="60"
       name=".ASPXAUTH" 
       path="/"
       requireSSL="false"
       slidingExpiration="true"
       defaultUrl="default.aspx"
       cookieless="UseDeviceProfile"
       enableCrossAppRedirects="false" />
</authentication>
```

But .ASPXAUTH cleared so soon (5 minutes I guess).

What is the probable reason?

Comment: You should really elaborate a little on "*so soon*", however, chances are your cookies are being cleared on the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very often, it is because you rebuild the solution. The web server restarts and `machineKey` are regenerated.

So the cookie encrypted and signed by previous `machineKey` is invalid.

That's why you are forced to log out.

Here is a quick one for you.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/436053/280970